# Boost spirit parse rule is not applied

Tags: c++, parsing, boost-spirit

i can´t see my error here .. this rule parse some stuff ok but the last two samples not. Could somebody please give me a hint ..

Goal is a parser than can identify member property access and member function calls. Also chained in some way

```
 a()
 a(para)
 x.a()
 x.a(para)
 x.a(para).g(para).j()
 x.y
 x.y.z
 x.y.z()    <---fail
 y.z.z(para) <--- fail
```

```
  lvalue =
         iter_pos >> name[_val = _1]
          >> *(lit('(') > paralistopt  > lit(')') >> iter_pos)[_val = construct<common_node>(type_cmd_fnc_call, LOCATION_NODE_ITER(_val, _2), key_this, construct<common_node>(_val), key_parameter, construct<std::vector<common_node> >(_1))]        
       >> *(lit('.') >> name_pure >> lit('(') > paralistopt > lit(')') >> iter_pos)[_val = construct<common_node>(type_cmd_fnc_call, LOCATION_NODE_ITER(_val, _3), key_this, construct<common_node>(_val), key_callname, construct<std::wstring>(_1), key_parameter, construct<std::vector<common_node> >(_2))]
       >> *(lit('.') >> name_pure >> iter_pos)[_val = construct<common_node>(type_cmd_dot_call, LOCATION_NODE_ITER(_val, _2), key_this, construct<common_node>(_val), key_propname, construct<std::wstring>(_1))]
    ;
```

thank you
  Markus

Comment: Can you describe what you are trying to achieve? What are you parsing, into what AST? I'm pretty sure your code is needlessly complicated. (See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259440/boost-spirit-semantic-actions-are-evil)

Comment: It seems your code sample is missing relevant bits too. If you include code, make it self-contained.

Answer (score 1):

You provide very little information to go at. Let me humor you with my entry into this guessing game:

Let's assume you want to parse a simple "language" that merely allows member expressions and function invocations, but chained.

Now, your grammar says nothing about the parameters (though it's clear the param list can be empty), so let me go the next mile and assume that you want to accept the same kind of expressions there (so `foo(a)` is okay, but also `bar(foo(a))` or `bar(b.foo(a))`).

Since you accept chaining of function calls, it appears that functions are first-class objects (and functions can return functions), so `foo(a)(b, c, d)` should be accepted as well.

You didn't mention it, but parameters often include literals (`sqrt(9)` comes to mind, or `println("hello world")`).

Other items:

- you didn't say but likely you want to ignore whitespace in certain spots
- from the `iter_pos` (ab)use it seems you're interested in tracking the original source location inside the resulting AST.

### 1. Define An AST

We should keep it simple as ever:

```
namespace Ast {
    using Identifier = boost::iterator_range<It>;

    struct MemberExpression;
    struct FunctionCall;

    using Expression = boost::variant<
                double,       // some literal types
                std::string,
                // non-literals
                Identifier,
                boost::recursive_wrapper<MemberExpression>,
                boost::recursive_wrapper<FunctionCall>
            >;

    struct MemberExpression {
        Expression object; // antecedent
        Identifier member; // function or field
    };

    using Parameter  = Expression;
    using Parameters = std::vector<Parameter>;

    struct FunctionCall {
        Expression function; // could be a member function
        Parameters parameters;
    };
}
```

> **NOTE** We're not going to focus on showing source locations, but already made one provision, storing identifiers as an iterator-range.
>
> **NOTE** Fusion-adapting the only types not directly supported by Spirit:
>
> ```
> BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Ast::MemberExpression, object, member)
> BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Ast::FunctionCall, function, parameters)
> ```
>
> We will find that we don't use these, because Semantic Actions are more convenient here.

### 2. A Matching Grammar

```
Grammar() : Grammar::base_type(start) {
    using namespace qi;
    start = skip(space) [expression];

    identifier = raw [ (alpha|'_') >> *(alnum|'_') ];
    parameters = -(expression % ',');

    expression 
        = literal 
        | identifier  >> *(
                    ('.' >> identifier)        
                  | ('(' >> parameters >> ')') 
                );

    literal = double_ | string_;
    string_ = '"' >> *('\\' >> char_ | ~char_('"')) >> '"';

    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES(
            (identifier)(start)(parameters)(expression)(literal)(string_)
        );
}
```

In this skeleton most rules benefit from automatic attribute propagation. The one that doesn't is `expression`:

```
qi::rule<It, Expression()> start;

using Skipper = qi::space_type;
qi::rule<It, Expression(), Skipper> expression, literal;
qi::rule<It, Parameters(), Skipper> parameters;
// lexemes
qi::rule<It, Identifier()> identifier;
qi::rule<It, std::string()> string_;
```

So, let's create some helpers for the semantic actions.

> **NOTE** An important take-away here is to create your own higher-level building blocks instead of toiling away with `boost::phoenix::construct<>` etc.

Define two simple construction functions:

```
struct mme_f { MemberExpression operator()(Expression lhs, Identifier rhs) const { return { lhs, rhs }; } };
struct mfc_f { FunctionCall operator()(Expression f, Parameters params) const { return { f, params }; } };
phx::function<mme_f> make_member_expression;
phx::function<mfc_f> make_function_call;
```

Then use them:

```
expression 
    = literal [_val=_1]
    | identifier [_val=_1] >> *(
                ('.' >> identifier)        [ _val = make_member_expression(_val, _1)]
              | ('(' >> parameters >> ')') [ _val = make_function_call(_val, _1) ]
            );
```

That's all. We're ready to roll!

### 3. DEMO

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/31b4dd9f613e1353)</kbd>**

I created a test bed looking like this:

```
int main() {
    using It = std::string::const_iterator;
    Parser::Grammar<It> const g;

    for (std::string const input : {
             "a()", "a(para)", "x.a()", "x.a(para)", "x.a(para).g(para).j()", "x.y", "x.y.z",
             "x.y.z()",
             "y.z.z(para)",
             // now let's add some funkyness that you didn't mention
             "bar(foo(a))",
             "bar(b.foo(a))",
             "foo(a)(b, c, d)", // first class functions
             "sqrt(9)",
             "println(\"hello world\")",
             "allocate(strlen(\"aaaaa\"))",
             "3.14",
             "object.rotate(180)",
             "object.rotate(event.getAngle(), \"torque\")",
             "app.mainwindow().find_child(\"InputBox\").font().size(12)",
             "app.mainwindow().find_child(\"InputBox\").font(config().preferences.baseFont(style.PROPORTIONAL))"
         }) {
        std::cout << " =========== '" << input << "' ========================\n";
        It f(input.begin()), l(input.end());

        Ast::Expression parsed;
        bool ok = parse(f, l, g, parsed);
        if (ok) {
            std::cout << "Parsed: " << parsed << "\n";
        }
        else
            std::cout << "Parse failed\n";

        if (f != l)
            std::cout << "Remaining unparsed input: '" << std::string(f, l) << "'\n";
    }
}
```

Incredible as it may appear, this already parses all the test cases and prints:

```
 =========== 'a()' ========================
Parsed: a()
 =========== 'a(para)' ========================
Parsed: a(para)
 =========== 'x.a()' ========================
Parsed: x.a()
 =========== 'x.a(para)' ========================
Parsed: x.a(para)
 =========== 'x.a(para).g(para).j()' ========================
Parsed: x.a(para).g(para).j()
 =========== 'x.y' ========================
Parsed: x.y
 =========== 'x.y.z' ========================
Parsed: x.y.z
 =========== 'x.y.z()' ========================
Parsed: x.y.z()
 =========== 'y.z.z(para)' ========================
Parsed: y.z.z(para)
 =========== 'bar(foo(a))' ========================
Parsed: bar(foo(a))
 =========== 'bar(b.foo(a))' ========================
Parsed: bar(b.foo(a))
 =========== 'foo(a)(b, c, d)' ========================
Parsed: foo(a)(b, c, d)
 =========== 'sqrt(9)' ========================
Parsed: sqrt(9)
 =========== 'println("hello world")' ========================
Parsed: println(hello world)
 =========== 'allocate(strlen("aaaaa"))' ========================
Parsed: allocate(strlen(aaaaa))
 =========== '3.14' ========================
Parsed: 3.14
 =========== 'object.rotate(180)' ========================
Parsed: object.rotate(180)
 =========== 'object.rotate(event.getAngle(), "torque")' ========================
Parsed: object.rotate(event.getAngle(), torque)
 =========== 'app.mainwindow().find_child("InputBox").font().size(12)' ========================
Parsed: app.mainwindow().find_child(InputBox).font().size(12)
 =========== 'app.mainwindow().find_child("InputBox").font(config().preferences.baseFont(style.PROPORTIONAL))' ========================
Parsed: app.mainwindow().find_child(InputBox).font(config().preferences.baseFont(style.PROPORTIONAL))
```

### 4. Too Good To Be True?

You're right. I cheated. I didn't show you this code required to debug print the parsed AST:

```
namespace Ast {
    static inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, MemberExpression const& me) {
        return os << me.object << "." << me.member;
    }

    static inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, FunctionCall const& fc) {
        os << fc.function << "(";
        bool first = true;
        for (auto& p : fc.parameters) { if (!first) os << ", "; first = false; os << p; }
        return os << ")";
    }
}
```

It's only debug printing, as string literals aren't correctly roundtripped. But it's only 10 lines of code, that's a bonus.

### 5. The Full Monty: Source Locations

This had your interest, so let's show it working. Let's add a simple loop to print all locations of identifiers:

```
using IOManip::showpos;

for (auto& id : all_identifiers(parsed)) {
    std::cout << " - " << id << " at " << showpos(id, input) << "\n";
}
```

Of course, this begs the question, what are `showpos` and `all_identifiers`?

```
namespace IOManip {
    struct showpos_t {
        boost::iterator_range<It> fragment;
        std::string const& source;

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, showpos_t const& manip) {
            auto ofs = [&](It it) { return it - manip.source.begin(); };
            return os << "[" << ofs(manip.fragment.begin()) << ".." << ofs(manip.fragment.end()) << ")";
        }
    };

    showpos_t showpos(boost::iterator_range<It> fragment, std::string const& source) {
        return {fragment, source};
    }
}
```

As for the identifier extraction:

```
std::vector<Identifier> all_identifiers(Expression const& expr) {
    std::vector<Identifier> result;
    struct Harvest {
        using result_type = void;
        std::back_insert_iterator<std::vector<Identifier> > out;
        void operator()(Identifier const& id)       { *out++ = id; }
        void operator()(MemberExpression const& me) { apply_visitor(*this, me.object); *out++ = me.member; }
        void operator()(FunctionCall const& fc)     {
            apply_visitor(*this, fc.function); 
            for (auto& p : fc.parameters) apply_visitor(*this, p);
        }
        // non-identifier expressions
        void operator()(std::string const&) { }
        void operator()(double) { }
    } harvest { back_inserter(result) };
    boost::apply_visitor(harvest, expr);

    return result;
}
```

That's a tree visitor that harvests all identifiers recursively, inserting them into the back of a container.

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/abe06a703f65b61c)</kbd>**

Where output looks like (excerpt):

```
 =========== 'app.mainwindow().find_child("InputBox").font(config().preferences.baseFont(style.PROPORTIONAL))' ========================
Parsed: app.mainwindow().find_child(InputBox).font(config().preferences.baseFont(style.PROPORTIONAL))
 - app at [0..3)
 - mainwindow at [4..14)
 - find_child at [17..27)
 - font at [40..44)
 - config at [45..51)
 - preferences at [54..65)
 - baseFont at [66..74)
 - style at [75..80)
 - PROPORTIONAL at [81..93)
```

Comment: Hi,
thank you very much for this hint. Your solution works very well and i was able to make all the calls and also chaining working on my Parser ! Greate help !
I Need some time to review the stuff with the "iter_pos", your solution Looks more native but i have some more complex items to track the positions from, not only identifier .. so i have to check how your solution will work here 
Markus

Comment: I'm happy to look at the the larger project. Indeed I'd suggest annotating AST nodes could be done orthogonally of the grammar (IIRC there was a compiler demo doing such things using `qi::on_error<success,....>`)

Comment: I remembered half-correctly: calc[78], conjure[123] and mini_c tutorials use `qi::on_success` with an "`annotation_function`". You might be interested in looking at those

Comment: got it ... nice workflow and no more iter_pos inside the parser! Thx again

Comment: @Markus I had some more fun with this http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3f354e40fb4da907 - there are a number of subtleties commented on. Note how you can uncomment the `AnnotateTag` base-class for `String` and get "magically" annotated String nodes (currently only the parent `Expression` node is annotated).

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
>> *(lit('.') >> name_pure >> lit('(') > paralistopt > lit(')'))
```

to

```
>> *(*(lit('.') >> name_pure) >> lit('(') > paralistopt > lit(')'))
```

Comment: this comment field makes me crazzy 8-) i put the rule with actions in the original post .. with your rule i dont´know how to apply my actions ..